# Cordova with Xcode not ignoring self-signed certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ssl, cordova

Completely and totally stumped with this issue. Have browsed through hundreds of posts which suggest the same solution given below, but am unable to reproduce the same effect, SSL certificate is not ignored. Same works on Chrome, FF. Not working as a Cordova-packaged iOS app on both simulator and device(tried on iOS 6.0.1, iOS 7.0.3, iOS 6.1)

End of AppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host{
     return YES;
}
@end
```

Console message:

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

Cordova 3.4.0 with Xcode 5.0.2; using plain javascript; xmlhttp.status = 404

Please tell me what is that I am missing?

Comment: Any suggestion will be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Has anybody recently used this Apple private API to bypass the self-signed SSL cert issue? Anybody at all. If not, I am considering using an alternative packager for iOS like Titanium or maybe Trigger.io.. Any thoughts on this?